# Mapinfo - Compare Road Direction

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic, road

I have two layers of Road Networks. How do I compare the difference in road direction between the two layers - both are polylines?

[image]

Comment: On a side note, you may want to record the direction for each side of the road. Depending on where you are, it can be valid to have ascending numbers on a side and descending numbers on the other side.

Comment: Thank you JGH I have done that in the address layer ☺

Comment: How are you expecting to do this, visually? Need a bit more information about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Show some example data and the desired result.

Comment: Hi T - I have two road layers, I have turned on the display road direction in both layers. In some minor roads I see that there is a difference in road direction between the two layers. I was just inquiring if there is maybe a SQL query that can highlight the roads that show a difference in direction. The network is massive and a Query might do it quickly. Thank You...

Comment: Are the lines similar or is there a chance that some of the lines have been split in one of the tables?

Comment: Do the individual lines share an ID?

Comment: All the lines are snapped and have only one section in both layers. They do not share a common ID except Road Name....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some pseudo-code on how you can do this.

For each road segment:

1. Find same road segment in the other dataset
2. Check if the distance from start point in road segment to start point in road segment from other dataset is within a tolerance
3. If it is the road segments have the same direction

You can achieve this using a small MapBasic script, and you can also do it using a SQL statement like the one below.

If you want to use the SQL, you might need to create some work on one of your datasets for it to be used in the SQL.

I'd recommend:

- add two float columns for coordinates from the first point
- creating a small buffer around the centroid to use this to find the matching record in the other dataset

The query could look like this:

```
Select *
  From Roads1, Roads2Buffer
  Where Roads1 Intersects Roads2Buffer.obj
  And Distance(ObjectNodeX(Roads1.obj,1,1), ObjectNodeY(Roads1.obj,1,1), Roads2Buffer.StartNodeX, Roads2Buffer.StartNodeY, "m") < 10
```

I join the two tables using the Intersects operator on the road segment from the first table and the buffer on the centroid in the other table.
I also specify that the distance between the start nodes in the two tables should be less than 10 meters.

The query finds the road segments that do have the same direction. If you are looking for those that aren't, use "> 10".

You can, of course, change the distance tolerance and you also need to decide on a reasonable buffer size to make sure you make it intersect.

Comment: Thank you Peter - its working great. As always you are a life saver.